# Hardware accelerated elliptic curve cryptography with low level access on IOS or Android

Tags: android, ios, cryptography

I want to demonstrate the performance of an elliptic curve based cryptographic algorithm on phones.
Therefore, I would need access to an API for *hardware accelerated* ECC, preferably P256 but other curves would work as well.
Since I am implementing a new algorithm, access to "high level" operations such as KeyGen is not sufficient.
Rather, I need access to raw curve operations such as point addition.

Digging in the official documentation, I cannot find any such API on neither iOS nor Android. Is there any way to obtain such access?

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS. It's unclear what is preventing you from writing your own Android software that uses your algorithms. Android cryptography is a provider-based architecture of medium-level cryptographic operations like "KeyGen", "Encrypt", "ECDSA", etc. and high-level constructs like TLS/SSL. You say such an API is not sufficient. But Android itself successfully uses this architecture to implement its hardware-backed enhanced security cryptographic API, so it's not clear why you can't do the same thing.

Comment: If you are referring to why I cannot use the basic building block of the high level API in android to implement my algorithm, it is since the algorithm is itself such a building block. If you are referring to why I cannot fork android and incirporate my own algorithm into the OS, I guess I technically could, but I eould like to be able to provide it to a general app developer.

Comment: The algorithm in question is available in Fig 3 at https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/242.pdf

Comment: When n is large, my software based implementation chokes due to inefficiency